# HMS Core AI Model Integration Error 403 on Template File Download when Using MindSpore Lite Inference Engine

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ml-kit

I'm using HMS Core Plugin - Model Integration from Coding Assistant to try to integrate my pre-trained model. I use MindSpore Lite inference engine and use caffemodel.

[Setup my caffemodel with MindSpore Lite Inference engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w3WZ.png)

When I try to finish my setup, it says "checkAndDownload" file not exists and trying to download. After that, I get a 403 error on template download from http://cdn.ide.deveco.huawei.com//ai/download/foundation/template-1.3.1.zip

[error 403 on download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Jvq.png)

Did I miss some configuration or it is a bug from the HMS plugin itself?

Comment: hi snippy,maybe you can refer this [link](https://www.mindspore.cn/tutorial/lite/en/master/use/converter_tool.html) and use this as a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error is an access forbidden error. The reason for the error can be that the directory does not exist, the index is wrong, or that they are unpermitted to access the information/download.
At this time, the download may not be accessible by you.